# Как пользоваться командной строкой через код?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

Как должен выглядеть код на python чтобы выполнить команду в командной строке? Допустим я просто запускаю свой код, а он сам вставляет команду в командную строку и запускает ее либо же просто выполняет команду командной строки?

Comment: Простейший вариант — `os.system("ls -l")`

Comment: @andreymal Действительно хороший, не знал о нём. Оформите, как ответ, пожалуйста.

Comment: Пользуюсь [**delegator.py**](https://github.com/kennethreitz/delegator.py). Причины выбора: простой синтаксис и дополнительные возможности. Без проблем, правда, [**не обходится**](https://github.com/kennethreitz/delegator.py/issues/59). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам может помочь модуль [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

***Пример:***

```py
import subprocess


subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```